# Typescript classes constructor order

Tags: typescript, class

I have a class that I initialize with a token.

This class then initializes another class to which it should pass this token.

I don't understand why the second class constructor is called before the main class constructor.

Is there any way to reverse the order?

Thanks.

```
// Main class
export class MainClass {

  token: string;

  constructor(t: string) {
    console.log("MainClass constructor", t);

    this.token = t;

  }
  private secondClass: SecondClass = new SecondClass(this.token);
}

// Second class
export class SecondClass {
  constructor(t: string) {
    console.log("SecondClass constructor",t);
  }
}


// Client code
const app = new MainClass("1234");

// Console
--> "SecondClass constructor undefined"
--> "MainClass constructor 1234"
```

Comment: That isn't a subclass, it's just another class.  Please consider changing your terminology so as to reduce confusion.

Comment: @jcalz sorry, you're right, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a little bit of a wrinkle with this question, since [class fields](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields) existed in TypeScript before they were [finally integrated into the ES2022 spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2022/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#prod-FieldDefinition), and depending on your compiler settings (such as [the `--useDefinedForClassFields` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier)) the compiled JavaScript might have somewhat different behavior.  But I think all of versions have the same initialization order.

In the [MDN documentation for class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#public_instance_fields) it says:

> Public instance fields are added ... either at construction time in the base class (before the constructor body runs), or just after `super()` returns in a subclass.

That means you can expect class fields to be initialized *before* the code in the `constructor` body.  And therefore your code is more or less the same as:

```
function MainClass(t) {
    this.secondClass = new SecondClass(this.token);
    console.log("MainClass constructor", t);
    this.token = t;
}
```

or maybe

```
function MainClass(t) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "token", {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: void 0
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, "secondClass", {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: new SecondClass(this.token)
    });
    console.log("MainClass constructor", t);
    this.token = t;
}
```

And either way, `new SecondClass(this.token)` runs before `this.token` is set to `t`.

---

The way around this is to initialize the properties inside the constructor body explicitly.  This lets you have more control over the order:

```
class MainClass {
    token: string;
    constructor(t: string) {
        console.log("MainClass constructor", t);
        this.token = t;
        this.secondClass = new SecondClass(this.token);
    }
    private secondClass: SecondClass;
}
```

Which should result in the expected:

```
[LOG]: "MainClass constructor",  "1234" 
[LOG]: "SecondClass constructor",  "1234"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=9&jsx=0&ts=4.7.4#code/PTAEFkEMEsDtQMYBtIGdUChltRGsBhFdUAbw1EtABcB7AawFNYAuUVagJzgHMBuClQS1YHTgFcEdTgApqbMbwCUZQVSEjUtJIwB0SWjxkAiKHCI5EmrpOnGANDSUD166gAtoqXXSbwAvDQurpQeXrqojMKwACYWJIGwjADuoADKUSJxxKhynt6+zM5qoAC+JQAO3ABukNSM7Jmx8ahsGdHZOALlGCDpTTGIOVg5-R0tqurRYra0svLsXMqTIVai2noGRsbtWRPTNlJzDk7BlOU9vWBE0MzUVjGMWNagkBUVoIkpeOY5JgCMACYAMwAFmMxSuoAImg2VwAtPCAHygHYDfbWCRHTigcSxRgAMzgjBixgRyNRZkIowOWOkoCBYLJQA)

Comment: This is not TypeScript-specific. It has to do with the [evaluation order of class definitions](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation) and would be true for the same code with types stripped.

Comment: TypeScript was compiling class fields to JS before that part of the spec was added in ES2022.  So it has *something* to do with TypeScript, at least to the extent that, depending on your compiler options, the resulting JS can act differently.  Luckily the evaluation order doesn't seem to be different... but it didn't *have* to be that way.  Just like ES settled on define semantics instead of set semantics, they could have decided on some other ordering, such as whether the field declaration appeared before or after the constructor body